# Emulating text user input in Angular webpage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i'm embedding a third party webpage into our WPF application (via WebBrowser control)... one of the goals is to preload some of the inputs on page load... the approach is to execute a few JS commands afterwards, which the WPF control supports, and is basically the same as using browser developer tools' JS console.

the webpage appears to be written using Angular (based on conversation w/ coworker it appears to be v1), jQuery is also available.

so far I've had no problem clicking some of the buttons (multi-select inputs) by using navigating the DOM (document.getElementById plus a few querySelector/etc calls) to the checkbox and calling .click()... in doing so the angular events fire, all is well.

the problem is with the text inputs... so far I've tried the following:

- doc.getElement().value = x;
- $(doc.getElement()).val(x);
- doc.getElement().value = x; angular.element(getElement).scope.$apply();
- doc.getElement().value = x; doc.getElement().dispatchEvent(new FocusEvent());

  - changes the textbox, but doesn't fire any events, and when I click into the textbox the text is reset back to the default (presumably from the Angular viewmodel)
- angular.element(doc.getElement()).scope().viewModel.data.whatever = x;
- angular.element(doc.getElement()).scope().viewModel.data.whatever = x; .scope().$apply();
- angular.element(doc.getElement()).scope().$apply(function(x) { x.data.viewPort.whatever = x;});

  - no effect in the UI, though any future calls to the viewmodel appear to keep the value (didn't try doing this before the .click() methods to see if it's recognized during the click() handling)

other ideas that i've had trouble testing:

- I tried setting value, setting focus on another element, then back to the original - just to see if the UI would refresh like it does for me interactively - it didn't.
- looks like the  has listeners on keypress, so i'd considered trying to simulate the event but was getting Permission Denied from Edge (I'd need to fiddle with Chrome's Kerberos settings to get it to work, and for reasons related to other internal sites, I've tried to avoid doing so).

looking for any and all suggestions.

I know the whole thing seems backwards, but i have no control over third party website (though I do have a call w/ their engineers in the next day or so) to discuss.

Comment: you need to **really clearly determine** if this is [tag:angularjs] (1.x) or [tag:angular] (2.x).  What you are asking about here is implementation specifics of the framework, but 1.x and 2.x are not the same framework at all, and have different approaches to DOM management.  Until you can determine which you are trying to manipulate, it will be very difficult to suggest strategies to solve your specific problem.

Comment: it definitely *seems* like angularjs, considering your use of `scope` objects.

Comment: due to how angularjs works, you may not really be able to achieve your goal the way you want.  because angularjs uses a two way data model, and the changes to the data model in javascript are replicated to the UI, the only way to actually modify the DOM is through the data model.  Changes to the DOM directly are not seen by angular, so angular just ends up replacing your changes with it's own updates.

Comment: the basis for the coworkers' believe in angular v1 over v2 was due to the ng-click and aria-label attributes in use... the edge JS console also had autocomplete for scope, $parent and $root for the scope'd objects... i'll check the headers of the referenced script files to try to have a specific version.

Comment: confirmed : @license AngularJS v1.5.7

Comment: Ok so the next question is, do you have the ability to extend their angular code, or is it sent minified?  Meaning, do you know what the code for the modules/controllers look like?